# SQL Expression Error - Warning: sqlite_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

Having a strange problem with my php code when i try and insert a record into my database.

```
$db=sqlite_open("Architect.db");

$CustomerNo = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT MAX(CustomerNo) FROM Customer");
$row=sqlite_fetch_array($CustomerNo);
$CustomerNumber= "$row[0]";

echo "CustomerNo: " . $CustomerNumber . "<br>";

$CustomerNumberup= ($CustomerNumber + 1);

echo "CustomerNo: " . $CustomerNumberup . "<br>";

//This is the function that actually adds things to the database.
function Store($Name,$Company,$PhoneNo,$Address1,$Address2,$County,$PostCode,$CustomerNumberup){

}
//this calls the function and passes it the variables
Store($Name,$Company,$PhoneNo,$Address1,$Address2,$County,$PostCode,$CustomerNumberup)
```

Basically i am getting the highest customer number, adding 1 to it and then using it as the customer number for the new entry.

On the output page i have asked for it to output the customer number at several stages.
It Shows CustomerNumber as 1 
It Shows CustomerNumberUp as 2
it then gives me the exact error

```
Warning: sqlite_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in I:\wwwroot\Year 3\Project Stuff\IP40 Website\addCustomer.php on line 52
```

Where linee 52 is the insert query.
I have tried allsorts to fix this, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: In addition to your problem, lookup the `max()` function's description http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html, your query does not seem to be correct, use `ORDER BY CustomerNo DESC LIMIT 1` instead. and clearly the error is in the `$db` variable, it is string instead of resource.

Comment: max can be used as an "aggregrate function" when only passed one variable as defined on that page.

"The max() aggregate function returns the maximum value of all values in the group. The maximum value is the value that would be returned last in an ORDER BY on the same column. Aggregate max() returns NULL if and only if there are no non-NULL values in the group."

Comment: you are right, learnt something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter 1 looks like the name to me.  Customer number comes at the end.

By the way, if your app ever gets busy, you will get duplicate customer numbers with your approach.  Does sqllite not have autoincrement fields?

Comment: I am only passing it into the function last, this shouldn't matter. I guarantee it is the first field. I have seen some information on auto increment fields but have never used them, i shall look into them

Comment: i have as you suggested looked into auto increment fields and have now changed CustomerNumber in this way, my code now works and inputs like this.

 sqlite_query($db,"INSERT INTO Customer (Name, Company, PhoneNo, Address1, Address2, County, Postcode)

             VALUES     ('$Name','$Company','$PhoneNo','$Address1','$Address2','$County','$PostCode')");

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your database name

```
$db=sqlite_open("Architect.db");
```

Does it work as intended if `.db` is removed?

Comment: All the code works exactly the same once this is removed. i still get the same error

Comment: i have found that another potential problem was that $db was declared outside of the function and so have declared it inside, this coupled with my new auto increment field has fixed it